# Did the top two runners in the 2000 Boston Marathon set identical times?

Tags: marathon

Why do Wikipedia and other sites claim that the 1st and 2nd-placed runners at the 2000 Boston Marathon set identical times?

The above video shows that the winner won by a full second. Why do these sources claim they set the same time?

Comment: For reference: crossing the finish line happens at 1:27:07 in the video

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, marathon times have not included fractions of seconds. The times are rounded up to the next second. Based on the video the second place finished within a second of the first, so it's reasonable to see the top 2 spots awarded the same time for this race.

Answer (score 1):

The identical times are reasonable.  The clock time above the runners is not 100% accurate -  while the elite runners are ["gun time"](https://www.baa.org/sites/default/files/2021-08/Boston_Marathon_Rules_and_Policies_08_2021.pdf) not "chip time", the official clock can be a small amount off of the display clock.  I'll trust the [ARRS](https://more.arrs.run/race/21119), which is as close as official as you can get for race time statistics; the [BAA page](https://www.baa.org/sites/default/files/2019-07/BostonMarathonHistoricalResults.pdf) also confirms this time.

As to whether the second place runner was within less than a second, they clearly are; by my calculation he finishes 2 to 2.5 strides behind, maybe 5 meters behind at most.  The runners are running just under 300 second miles on average, and as elite marathoners they're pretty consistent - plus the adrenaline of being at the end suggests they're at least at their average for the last few paces.  300 second miles means those 2.5-ish steps (or 5 meters) take 0.9 seconds or thereabouts - so plausible they are "in" the same second (and it may be more like 0.7 if it's 2 strides, or 4 meters). Of course, the second could tick during that 0.7-0.9 seconds; but it's also possible it doesn't.